# Java: Solving 15 Puzzle using Fitness functions

Tags: puzzle, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, fitness

I am currently working on a project to solve a 15 Puzzle using fitness functions. There are 3 kinds of fitness functions that can be used,

1. Fitness function1= 1 - (number of misplaced tiles/total number of tiles);
2. Fitness function2= 1- (sum of distances of all misplaced tiles from goal position/64)
3. Fitness function3= (Fitness 2+ Fitness 1 )/2

The solver is meant to search for possible moves that improves the fitness function VALUE until the whole puzzle board is solved (where fitness function=1).
I am stocked while trying to generate moves because the solver print unsuccessful search routes along with the actual route e.g. W,S,W,N,S,N,S,N,S,N,S,N,S,N,S,N,S,N ( which is in reverse order) and means NWSW. However the solver searches back and forth several times and also prints the unwanted routes. 
I would want to exclude previously visited locations in the recursion and also print only the valid moves and not the unsuccessful moves.
The code is available below:

```
<pre><code>
enter code here

package Definitions;

public class Puzzle {
public TreeNode boardsTree;
public Boolean searching;
public int lastPos;


Puzzle(Board b) {
 boardsTree = new TreeNode(b);
 lastPos = b.Blank_pos;
}

public String solver(Board b, String route, int level, double fitVal){
//System.out.println("route in the level " + level +": " +route + " Fitness: ");                          
//System.out.print(b.f1.getFitnessVal()); 
//If the depth of the Tree is level 15 or Board is solved return route(moves e.g. WNS)
if(level == 15||b.solved){
//if(route != ""){
//if(route.length()>1){
// return route.substring(0, route.length()-1);
//}else{
return route;
//}
}else{
//Create a temporary store for the last position 
//Create four auxilliary puzzle boards has child puzzles
//Perform the different moves on the blank space on each board in different directions      
//(N=0,S=1,E=2,W=3)
lastPos = b.Blank_pos;
Board auxN = new Board(4,b.tilesList);
Board auxS = new Board(4,b.tilesList);
Board auxE = new Board(4,b.tilesList);
Board auxW = new Board(4,b.tilesList);
//Builds the tree

//MOVES TO NORTH
//b.isValidMove(North=0,South=1,East=2,West=3)
if( b.isValidMove(0)){ 
 //If the lastPosition (blankPosition in the parent board) is not the position of the  
 //cell in the north MoveBlank to North
 if(lastPos != (lastPos - 4)){
 auxN.MoveBlank(0);
 boardsTree.addSon(0,auxN);
 if(fitVal > boardsTree.getSon(0).getState().f1.getFitnessVal()){
  auxN.print();
  searching = false;
  return route + "N"; 
    }
   }
  }

//MOVES TO SOUTH
//b.isValidMove(North=0,South=1,East=2,West=3)
if( b.isValidMove(1) ){ 
 //If the lastPosition (blankPosition in the parent board) is not the position of the  
 //cell in the north MoveBlank to North
if(lastPos != (lastPos + 4)){
 auxS.MoveBlank(1);
 boardsTree.addSon(1,auxS);
 if(fitVal > boardsTree.getSon(1).getState().f1.getFitnessVal()){
  auxS.print();
  searching = false;
  return route + "S"; 
   }
  }
 }

 //MOVES TO EAST
 if( b.isValidMove(2) ){
    if(lastPos != (lastPos + 1)){
       auxE.MoveBlank(2);
       boardsTree.addSon(2,auxE);
       if(fitVal > boardsTree.getSon(2).getState().f1.getFitnessVal()){
       auxE.print();
       searching = false;
       return route + "E";
     }
    }
   }

//MOVES TO WEST
if( b.isValidMove(3) ){ 
if(lastPos != (lastPos -1)){
 auxW.MoveBlank(3);
 boardsTree.addSon(3,auxW);
 if(fitVal > boardsTree.getSon(3).getState().f1.getFitnessVal()){
  auxW.print();
  searching = false;
  return route + "W"; 
  }
 }
}

//EVALUATE NEW STATES

if(searching && b.isValidMove(0)){
  System.out.println("Actual: " +auxN.Blank_pos+ " Previo: "+lastPos );
  if(lastPos != auxN.Blank_pos){
     lastPos = auxN.Blank_pos;
     route = solver(auxN,route + "N", level+1, fitVal); //NORTH
     }else{
     //If  a solution is not generated enter a recursion to find further solutions at a    
     //further depth of the tree
     solver(auxN,route, level+1, fitVal); //NORTH
          }
 }
 if(searching  && b.isValidMove(1)){
  //System.out.println("Actual: " +auxS.Blank_pos+ " Previo: "+lastPos );
  if(lastPos != auxS.Blank_pos){
    lastPos = auxS.Blank_pos;
    route =solver(auxS,route + "S", level+1, fitVal); //NORTH
  }else{
    solver(auxS,route, level+1, fitVal); //NORTH
      }
 }
 if(searching  && b.isValidMove(2)){
   //System.out.println("Actual: " +auxE.Blank_pos+ " Previo: "+lastPos );
   if(lastPos != auxE.Blank_pos){
   lastPos = auxE.Blank_pos;
   route = solver(auxE,route + "E", level+1, fitVal); //NORTH
   }else{
   solver(auxE,route, level+1, fitVal); //NORTH
        }
   }
   if(searching  && b.isValidMove(3)){
    //System.out.println("Actual: " +auxW.Blank_pos+ " Previo: "+lastPos );
     if(lastPos != auxW.Blank_pos){
     lastPos = auxW.Blank_pos;
     route =solver(auxW,route + "W", level+1, fitVal); //NORTH
     }else{
     solver(auxW,route, level+1, fitVal); //NORTH
           }
      }
     }
     return route;

     }
     }
```

Comment: five tags, all but Java, used for a Java puzzle

Comment: It sounds very much like you "borrowed" this code and don't know how it works. Your request to not print unsuccessful moves is blatant.

Comment: @Sparr: I wrote this code and I know how it works perfectly. The problem I am having is on how to optimize the search and get rid of unsuccessful search routes. The key here is that each time we search for a solution among a maximum of four adjacent neighbors and we don't find a solution, we step into each node(neighbor) and perform the same operation once again and a new board with the new configuration is created to facilitate this search. WE continue to perform this by calling recursively solver(Board b, String route, int level, double fitVal) until we arrive at a solution.